# Python using QGridLayout not add widget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm new to Qt5, I have a simple QGridLayout layout mask . 
I want to create a windows with the widget resize with resize of window

this is the code

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog ,QVBoxLayout,QGroupBox,QGridLayout

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, QtWidgets.QFileDialog, QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title = "Calcolo Hash"
        self.top = 100
        self.left = 100
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 330

        self.InitWindow()

    def InitWindow(self):
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icona_aprie.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)

        self.creamaschera()

        self.show()

    def creamaschera(self):
        print ("creazione maschera")
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.txtcartella = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lblprova = QtWidgets.QLabel("Please enter new name:")
        # self.txtcartella.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 301, 20))
        # self.txtcartella.setObjectName("txtcartella")
        layout.addWidget(self.lblprova,0,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.txtcartella,0,1)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        # self.horizontalGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    #w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

but when I run the mask is empy. 
I make the base with Qt5 designer and convert it to python. I want to refactor the class in a best workout.
Where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should setLayout in a widget rather than setting it to the MainWindow since you are using the MainWindow class itself and while accessing the methods and  properties of the class MainWindow you can be more specific

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QWidget,
                             QGridLayout, QLabel, QApplication)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title = "Calcolo Hash"
        self.top = 100
        self.left = 100
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 330
        self.InitWindow()
    def InitWindow(self):
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icona_aprie.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)

        self.creamaschera()

    def creamaschera(self):
        print("creazione maschera")
        Layout = QGridLayout()
        self.txtcartella = QLineEdit()
        self.lblprova = QLabel("Enter Your Name")
        self.lblprova.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 15, 301, 20))
        self.txtcartella.setObjectName("txtcartella")
        Layout.addWidget(self.lblprova, 0, 0)
        Layout.addWidget(self.txtcartella, 0, 1)
        # Widget to setLayout in it since you are using MainWindow as an Class
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(Layout)
        # SetCentralWidget without this widget won't be placed
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        # self.horizontalGroupBox.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```